# Why is serializer.ToStream null in NpgSql?

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, npgsql

I get null exception on NpgSqlCopyIn line.

serializer is NOT null but ToStream is - why?

```
    string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", <removed creds>);
    NpgsqlConnection dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);


    NpgsqlCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
    string sql = "COPY MIN_BAR_LASTS FROM STDIN;";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
    NpgsqlCopySerializer serializer = new NpgsqlCopySerializer(dbcon);
    NpgsqlCopyIn copyIn = new NpgsqlCopyIn(dbcmd, dbcon, serializer.ToStream);

    copyIn.Start();

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\PostgreSQLLoadFile.txt");
    foreach(var line in lines){
        serializer.AddString(line);
        serializer.EndRow();
        serializer.Flush();
    }
    copyIn.End();
    serializer.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to debug your application? do you know how to debug applications?

Comment: @GottZ - That's how I know what line there error is on.

Comment: so did you set a breakpoint some lines before, debug it, step into function calls and figure out whats going wrong or did you just let it throw?

Comment: @GottZ - I stepped through and got error on NpgsqlCopyIn line saying serializer.ToStream() is null

Comment: i just notice in your code there is no `()` behind `ToStream`. is that how its supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, it is a non-invokable member. I have added snip of error to question

Comment: Note that you're using the old Npgsql 2.2 API, Npgsql 3.0 has a totally new copy API which works much better